# I keep getting perhaps a missing \item error

Tags: algorithmicx

I'm having problems with my LaTeX code. I keep getting an error:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [13]

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.461 \end{algorithmic}
```

---

LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{ glavna\_zanka }%function 
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While{ končaj $\not=$ false } 
\State $ rotiraj\_robota()$
 \State obrobje o = $izberi\_raziskovalni\_cilj()$
\If { o $\neq$ null } 
    \State $ premakni\_do\_cilja(o)$
\Else
    \State  končaj = true
\EndIf
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{ izberi\_raziskovalni\_cilj() }
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any insight into the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This is because you're having `\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\end{algorithmic}` and nothing in between!

Answer (score 2):

There are some lines of a code in the body of `algorithmic` expected. Please compare a compilable example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{ glavna\_zanka }%function 
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While{ končaj $\not=$ false } 
\State $ rotiraj\_robota()$
 \State obrobje o = $izberi\_raziskovalni\_cilj()$
\If { o $\neq$ null } 
    \State $ premakni\_do\_cilja(o)$
\Else
    \State  končaj = true
\EndIf
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}



\begin{algorithm}
\caption{ izberi\_raziskovalni\_cilj() }
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

BTW: `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` rarely means, that there is a missing item; at least according to my experience. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It seems the algorithmic environment requires to have a content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{ glavna\_zanka }%function
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \While{ končaj $\not=$ false }
    \State $ rotiraj\_robota()$
    \State obrobje o = $izberi\_raziskovalni\_cilj()$
    \If { o $\neq$ null }
    \State $ premakni\_do\_cilja(o)$
    \Else
    \State končaj = true
    \EndIf
    \EndWhile
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{izberi\_raziskovalni\_cilj()}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Lalala…
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]